# I can't register user in my user registration form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a user registration form, every thing looks fine but when I try to register new user it brings back the same form while I redirected it to home page. Also when I go to admin to look for new registered user, I see nothing

This is for python 3.7.3, django 2.2.3 and mysql 5.7.26. I have tried to check and recheck every thing seems to be ok but still I can't achieve what I want

forms.py

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User 
    fields = ("username","email","password1","password2")
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

        login(request, user)
        return redirect("loststuffapp:IndexView")
    else:
        for msg in user_form.error_messages:
            print(user_form.error_messages[msg])
else:
    user_form = UserCreationForm
return render(
                request,
                "loststuffapp/register.html",
                context={"user_form":user_form}

    )
```

register.html

```
{% extends "loststuffapp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{user_form.as_p}}
       <button type="submit" style="background-color: 
      yellow">Register</button>>
      If you already have an account, <a href="/Register">login</a> instead
   {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to authenticate the user before you can login. See the example below, taken from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

```
# Taken from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my views as you can see above but still I face same problem. I guess it skip the if section and it take the return only, please help!!

Comment: I have came to realize, i was not following password naming rules plus I have not customized messages, at least that will make me aware of what is going on